# Sanitize text which seem normal but it's not (different encoding?) in R

Tags: r, text, encoding, string-matching, data-cleaning

I'm facing an odd situation. I need to analyze and clean some text found on the internet. One of such documents is like this (Italian):

> "L'Antitrust: sull'acquisto dei vaccini a uso umano opportuna una ... - ІL Cоrrіеrе dеllа Cіttà L'Antitrust chiede maggiore trasparenza sulla definizione dei costi e dei prezzi dei vaccini, che in Italia costano ogni anno almeno 300 milioni di euro al servizio sanitario nazionale, e propone di inserirli nelle classi di rimborso dei farmaci per ..."

The part "ІL Cоrrіеrе dеllа Cіttà" seems made by normal character but instead it's not (try to use your browser search function with those words).

I need to clean the text from stopwords ("il" and "della" in this case), but I cannot match the words in that part with my list of stopwords.

Is there a way to sanitize such strange characters to normal UTF-8 characters?

Thanks

UPDATE:
as asked in the comments I run `dput(charToRaw("ІL Cоrrіеrе dеllа Cіttà"))` copying and pasting the strange text:

```
as.raw(c(0xd0, 0x86, 0x4c, 0x20, 0x43, 0xd0, 0xbe, 0x72, 0x72, 
0xd1, 0x96, 0xd0, 0xb5, 0x72, 0xd0, 0xb5, 0x20, 0x64, 0xd0, 0xb5, 
0x6c, 0x6c, 0xd0, 0xb0, 0x20, 0x43, 0xd1, 0x96, 0x74, 0x74, 0xc3, 
0xa0))
```

And this is the output of `dput(charToRaw("IL Corriere della Città"))`, this time written by hand:

```
as.raw(c(0x49, 0x4c, 0x20, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x72, 0x69, 0x65, 
0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x20, 0x43, 0x69, 
0x74, 0x74, 0xc3, 0xa0))
```

Comment: This is very odd. `s <- "L'Antitrust: sull'acquisto dei vaccini a uso umano opportuna una ... - ІL Cоrrіеrе dеllа Cіttà" ; words <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(s), " ")); words[words %in% c("il", "della")]` returns nothing, as you say. But if you replace `c("il", "della")` by copying and pasting the appropriate words from `dput(words)` (even if it looks identical on the screen), you will get those words returned.

Comment: could you post `dput(charToRaw(input))` ?

Comment: done as an update of the question, thx!